# Python Pandas - Fuzzy duplicates matching

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
    make                model
0   allard              K1
1   alllard             J2
2   alpine renault      A110
3   alpine renualt      A310
4   amc (rambler        American
5   amc (rambler)       Marlin
6   aries               1907
7   ariès               1932
8   austin healey       3000
9   austin-healey       Sprite
10  benjamin et benova  Type B3
11  benjamin/benova     Type P2
12  benjmin/benova      Type P3
```

The goal would be to have a third column with the index of the row which has the highest fuzzy ratio (closest fuzzy match).

How could I compare rows together in an efficient way?

Comment: Are you referring to the `make` column or some combination of the two columns?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy), and assuming the fuzziness should be matched for the `make` column, you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
from fuzzywuzzy.fuzz import ratio

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
keys = list(set(df['make']))
ratios = pd.DataFrame([{'k1': k1, 'k2': k2, 'ratio': ratio(k1, k2)} for k1, k2 in product(keys, keys) if k1 != k2])

def find_closest(make):
    return df[df['make'] == ratios.loc[ratios[ratios['k1'] == make]['ratio'].argmax(), 'k2']].index.values[0]

df['closest_index'] = df['make'].apply(find_closest)

print(df)
```

Output for your data:

```
                  make     model  closest_index
0               allard        K1              1
1              alllard        J2              0
2       alpine renault      A110              3
3       alpine renualt      A310              2
4         amc (rambler  American              5
5        amc (rambler)    Marlin              4
6                aries      1907              7
7                ariès      1932              6
8        austin healey      3000              9
9        austin-healey    Sprite              8
10  benjamin et benova   Type B3             11
11     benjamin/benova   Type P2             12
12      benjmin/benova   Type P3             11
```

Comment: Ok. Super cool, that's what I wanted. Two things though: first, in the `find_closest` definition, `res` should be replaced by `ratios`. Second, do you think I could use this method if I have 200 000 rows?

Comment: Thanks, fixed it :)

Comment: Regarding scale, how many unique `make`s do you expect to have? I would expect that initially removing duplicates will significantly filter the results, and then running the `ratio` calculation shouldn't be too heavy

Comment: I was thinking to use the same method for `model`s as well. Once duplicates are removed, I end up having about 40 000 rows. As you might understand, my concern is about the `itertools.product`..

Comment: Yes, I understand why that would be problematic. There are several things I would try:
1) Cut the amount of `ratio` calculations by half (only calculating for `k1, k2` and inserting result also as `k2, k1`).
2) Try to bucket all existing values (e.g. by total string length in multiples of 5) and make `product` comparisons only within buckets.